# Ordered Bullet List using Arabic letters in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-lists, bullet

I would like to make a bullet list of arabic text in html like the following:

> أ. السطرالأول
>
> ب. السطرالثاني
>
> ت. السطرالثالث
>
> ث. السطرالرابع

I tried a couple things including:

```
li {
    list-style: AL;
}

@counter-style AL {
    symbols: 'أ' 'ب' 'ت' 'ث'
    suffix: " ";
}
```

but it is not working. Is it possible to do it and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a workaround, and it works:

1: set the `list-style-type` to none.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

2: in your script create an array that holds the arabic letters html hex codes.

```
var bulletclasses = [" - &#x0623"," - &#x0628"," - &#x062A"];
var i = 0;
```

3: then when you append a new line to the list, include the hex code with your text.

```
$("ul").append("<li>" + todoText + bulletclasses[i] + "</li>");
i = i + 1;
```

I am not good with `JS` and `CSS`, there might be another way better and cleaner than this, but dynamically setting the symbols can do the job, supposing your list won't exceed 28 items.

I also thought about creating a `CSS` class for each Arabic letter then whenever you want to add a new item to list you add this class to each `<li>` using `js` , that would be tedious.

[you can find the hex codes here](https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/writing-systems/%EF%BA%95%EF%BA%8F%D8%A2-arabic-alphabet/)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, both [`symbols()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/symbols) and [`@counter-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style) have practically no browser support as of 2020.

But, here is a working CSS-only solution, based on [an example from W3C](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/color-bullets.en.html):

```css
ol.abjd {
  list-style: none;
}

ol.abjd > li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  margin-right: -1.5em;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  text-align: left;
  direction: ltr;
}

ol.abjd > li:nth-child(1)::before  { content: ".أ"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(2)::before  { content: ".ب"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(3)::before  { content: ".جـ"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(4)::before  { content: ".د"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(5)::before  { content: ".هـ"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(6)::before  { content: ".و"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(7)::before  { content: ".ز"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(8)::before  { content: ".حـ"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(9)::before  { content: ".ط"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(10)::before { content: ".ى"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(11)::before { content: ".كـ"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(12)::before { content: ".ل"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(13)::before { content: ".مـ"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(14)::before { content: ".ن"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(15)::before { content: ".س"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(16)::before { content: ".عـ"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(17)::before { content: ".ف"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(18)::before { content: ".صـ"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(19)::before { content: ".ق"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(20)::before { content: ".ر"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(21)::before { content: ".ش"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(22)::before { content: ".ت"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(23)::before { content: ".ث"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(24)::before { content: ".خـ"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(25)::before { content: ".ذ"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(26)::before { content: ".ضـ"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(27)::before { content: ".ظ"; }
ol.abjd > li:nth-child(28)::before { content: ".غـ"; }
```

Note that this code only styles `<ol>`s that have the class `abjd`. Example:

```html
<ol class="abjd">
  <li>عنصر 1</li>
  <li>عنصر 2</li>
  …
</ol>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bycn1xh6/1/)

I used `U+0640 ARABIC TATWEEL` instead of `U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER` after some letters, because I find it looking better. Customize as you like.